# Getting Error button on swagger UI that is schemaValidationMessages

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

When I am using localhost in SwaggerUIBundle URL it works fine and does not show error button

SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "http://localhost:9001/api/docs/data"
});

but when I use IP address instead of localhost, error button appear on the page and clicking on error button getting this message.

{"schemaValidationMessages":[
  {
    "level":"error",
    "message":"Can't read from file http://10.100.160.420:9001/api/docs/swagger.json"
  }
]}

I don't want to use **validatorUrl: null**, Please don't answer to use this **validatorUrl: null**. I just want to know why it is not working with IP address but working with localhost ?

Answer (score 4):

> I don't want to use validatorUrl: null, Please don't answer to use this validatorUrl: null. I just want to know why it is not working with IP address but working with localhost ?

Swagger UI does not display the validator badge in the following cases:

- `validatorUrl: null` configuration option is specified
- URL of the API definition (YAML/JSON file) contains `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Source: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/components/online-validator-badge.jsx#L40

That's why the validator badge does not appear if you use `http://localhost/...` but appears if you use `http://10.100.160.420:9001/...`.

Comment: if host is 0.0.0.0 then it appears